# Cannot display gpio documentation over "man gpio" command

Tags: locale

I would like to configure my gpio pins, but I cannot dipslay documentation over `man gpio` command. This is the result of command:

```
man: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
No manual entry for gpio
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Can anybody tell me where is the problem?

```
> locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_TIME=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_NAME=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I set `LC_ALL` by adding a line to `.bashrc`:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: You may want to use `raspi-config` (*Internationalisation Options -> Set up language and regional settings*) to correct the locale properly.  This may require a reboot or a log out and back in again, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Presumably the gpio utility is not installed.

The gpio utility is bundled with the wiringPi library.

Install wiringPi (if using Raspbian) with

`sudo apt-get install wiringpi`

The gpio command should then work.

---

EDITED TO ADD

My assumption is wrong, the man pages are not installed with the Raspbian wiringPi package.

One work around is

```
git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi

cd wiringPi

cd gpio

sudo cp gpio.1 /usr/local/man/man1
```

Comment: I already have installed wiringpi. Do you havy any other idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: No, you must have installed wiringPi in a non-standard way.

Comment: Well, I admit I can't remember how I installed wiringPi. I unninstalled it right now by `sudo apt-get --purge remove wiringpi` command and install it again by `sudo -apt-get install wiringpi`. It did not help.

Comment: @dorinand My apologies, I thought the man pages were installed as part of the wiringPi package.  I've just re-installed myself and they are not.

Comment: It is no problem. Do you have any idea how to solve this ? I can find documentation about gpio on the internet, but I would like to have it reacheable over terminal.

Comment: @dorinand I have edited my answer to suggest a work around.

Comment: I did it step by step but the problem persist.

Comment: @dorinand I'm out of ideas.  Does man work with any pages?  e.g. does man strlen return a page?

Comment: Yes, it is work fine. I use it normaly for other commands but it not working for gpio. Thank you enyway. When I will find out where is the problem, I will add a comment here.

Comment: Does the command manpath show /usr/local/man?

Comment: It shows this:  `manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man`

Comment: All that I have left is to try @goldilocks suggestion of setting the locale properly with `sudo raspi-config`.

Answer (score 4):

You should fix the `locale` and other internationalisation options (using `raspi-config` and not trying to manually configure). This issue is unrelated to `gpio`.

`gpio` was NOT included with `Wheezy` and required manual installation but was included with `Jessie`. Unfortunately something in the update process seemed to have removed `gpio` in full or part as it uninstalled the `wiringpi` library.

I asked questions about this, but never managed to get a satisfactory answer. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=148471&p=976588&hilit=+wiringpi#p976588

I "fixed" this with

```
sudo apt-get purge wiringpi
sudo apt-get install wiringpi
```

This is preferable to the manual installation procedure, as it will ensure the latest version is installed.

As joan has pointed out the `man` pages for `gpio` are not installed by the manual procedure or from the repository, but can be added.

Answer (score 0):

$ cd
$ git clone https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi.git
$ cd ~/wiringPi
$ ./build

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/129440)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).