# gpio: command not found

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, snappy

With my raspbian I used to use the command `gpio`. Unfortunately, I forgot how I installed it, or if it came installed by default in Raspbian.

Now I'm playing with UbuntuCore for RaspberryPi, and I have the need of using this command again, but it's not clear how to install it.

By googling around, I've seen people recommending installing these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
sudo pip install wiringPi
sudo pip install gpio
```

But that doesn't bring the `gpio` command, apparently.

The commands I want to launch via gpio are this kind:

```
gpio mode 0 out
gpio write 0 1
gpio write 0 0
```

How can I install gpio?

Comment: The tool that provides a syntax you describe should come with wiringpi http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/

Comment: I already said that I installed wiringPi through `sudo pip install` and that doesn't make gpio command appear

Comment: I had the same problem in debian, solve -> https://command-not-found.com/gpiodetect

Comment: Just joining the party and though I tried the above mentioned solutions, none worked with my Rpi4b. However this site had a solution that worked for me:
https://category.yahboom.net/blogs/news/raspberry-pi-1?comment=133519966524#comments

Comment: @pademo57 you should post that as an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 4):

A little bit late, but as can be found here: http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/
simply type

```bsh
sudo apt-get install wiringpi
```

This installs the `gpio` command.

Comment: WiringPi is deprecated - most of the links DO NOT WORK, and the latest source is UNAVAILABLE!

Comment: Last ever version of wiringPi is available from http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-updated-to-2-52-for-the-raspberry-pi-4b/

Comment: you should read [here](http://wiringpi.com/news/) and understand why motivation to support recent devices is low

Answer (score 2):

`sudo pip install` won't work, because it is NOT a Python program.

The following answer explains how to install it and also how to get the missing `man` pages. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51378/8697

Comment: wiringpi doesn't seem to be available for this version of ubuntu (ubuntu-core snappy?)

Comment: If it is not in the distribution, you can always install it from source http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/

Answer (score 2):

```sh
docker run --rm --device /dev/ttyAMA0:/dev/ttyAMA0 --device /dev/mem:/dev/mem --privileged -ti python:2 /bin/sh
apt-get update && apt-get install git-core sudo
git clone https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi --depth 1
cd WiringPi/
./build
gpio readall
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your pip is pip3 you can try this code.

```
sudo apt install python-pip3 python-dev
sudo pip3 install RPi.GPIO
sudo pip3 install wiringPi
sudo pip3 install gpio
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wiringpi.com.

As of the end of 2023, you'll not find anything here anymore. It's gone.

Email if you want - if you know my email address. Work it out.

-Gordon