# how to read output of gpio readall

Tags: wiringpi

I never used `wiringpi` library before. I'm trying to understand how to read the output of `gpio readall`. What are the `BCM` and `wPi` columns? What does `ALT0` mode mean? I searched online for output explanation but couldn't find anything. I found the following website, http://wiringpi.com/, but there is no full explanation of `gpio readall`  Below is the output of my `gpio readall`

```
pi@cyb3:~ $ gpio readall
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 1 |  7 || 8  | 0 | IN   | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | IN   | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI | ALT0 | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO | ALT0 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK | ALT0 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | OUT  | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | OUT  | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 |   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
 |   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
 |  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
 |  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 3---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: `altX` are the alternate functions of a pin. See [here](http://www.dummies.com/computers/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-gpio-pin-alternate-functions/). `BCM` is the pin number when using `GPIO` (aka `BCM`) numbering scheme, and `wPi` is the pin number when using the wiringPi's own pin numbering scheme. So when using wiringPi, if you choose `wiringPiSetup()`, it'll default to using the `wPi` pin numbers, and `wiringPiSetupGpio()` will result in using the GPIO/BCM numbers.

Comment: `man gpio` **SHOULD** install the documentation, however it is missing. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51347/8697 for detail of how to install it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ALTx` signifies the alternate functions of a pin. See [this](http://www.dummies.com/computers/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-gpio-pin-alternate-functions/) for a better understanding.

`BCM` is the pin number when using `GPIO` (aka BCM) numbering scheme, and `wPi` is the pin number when using the wiringPi's own pin numbering scheme. So when using wiringPi, if you choose `wiringPiSetup()`, it'll default to using the wPi pin numbers, and `wiringPiSetupGpio()` will result in using the GPIO/BCM numbers.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great write up on this at https://iotbreaks.com/understand-gpio-readall-bash-shell-command-output-on-raspberry-pi/

In keeping with the "Good answers" guidelines, I'll plagiarize the relevant part:

> ## “Physical” column
>
> This is the pin number on the connector. it is simply the physical number which is marked as the following picture.
>   We can easily count its 40 pins without caring the functions.
>
> [image: RaspberryPi GPIO PINs]
>
> ## “V” column
>
> This indicates the voltage level of the pins. As you may notice, the “0/1” value is applicable for GPIO pins only, and leave
>   blank for the rest. V=0 indicates the voltage level on the pin is LOW,
>   the exact voltage value is 0V. In contrast, V=1 indicates the voltage
>   level on the pin is HIGH, the exact voltage value is 3.3V.
>
> ## “Mode” column
>
> The “Mode” shows how the pin is being used. Here is the list of valid modes able to set for GPIO:
>   in/out/pwm/clock/up/down/tri. However, you also see the “ALT[#]”
>   listed in the Mode column. This ALT[#] indicates the GPIO pin is being
>   used as alternative function – a specific function, not as general
>   purpose function.
>
> - in: the GPIO pin is used as input without software-register-pull-up or software-register-pull-down. In this mode, if the pin is not
>     connected to any reference point, the input state will be unknown (it
>     is floated).
> - out: the GPIO pin is used as output, and without software-register-pull-up or software-register-pull-down. In this
>     mode, if the pin is not connected to any reference point, the input
>     state will be unknown (it is floated).
> - pwm: the GPIO pin is used as hardware Pulse-Width-Modulation mode which is square waveform generation. This mode is usually used to
>     control DC motor speed or LED dimming. Keep in mind that only BCM 18
>     (or GPIO.1) supports PWM output mode.
> - clock: the GPIO pin is used as clock generater. The frequency of clock is driven from main crystal frequency of Raspberry Pi. Note that
>     only BCM 4 (or GPIO.7) supports CLOCK output mode.
> - up: The GPIO pin is used as input with software-register-pull-up. In this mode, if the pin is not connected to any reference point, the
>     input state will be HIGH (or 1).
> - down: The GPIO pin is used as input with software-register-pull-down. In this mode, if the pin is not connected
>     to any reference point, the input state will be LOW (or 0).
> - tri: The GPIO pin is used as input without software-register-pull-down or up. In this mode, if the pin is not
>     connected to any reference point, the input state will be LOW or HIGH.
> - ALT[#]: The GPIO pin is used as a special function. You can check the list of those special functions at this link.
>
> ## “Name” column
>
> This show the names of pins. The name hints
>   us the functions of pins. It is also used as BOARD number when we use
>   GPIO.BOARD mode. This uses P1 header pin numbering convention.
>
> ## “wPi” column
>
> This is simply a “GPIO”-removed text of “Name” column.
>
> ## “BCM” column
>
> This is the number of AMR peripherals. we use this number with “gpio” command. For example, “gpio mode 22 in” means that
>   we use BCM 6 pin(Physical-31/Name-GPIO.22) as an input, “gpio -g mode 22 in” means that
>   we use BCM 22 pin(Physical-15/Name-GPIO.3) as an input.

Comment: From anonymous edit: The example in the last line in the "BCM" column contains wrong information. It should be "BCM 6 pin(Physical-31/Name-GPIO.22) as an input, `gpio -g mode 22 in` means that we use BCM 22 pin(Physical-15/Name-GPIO.3) as an input."